# A "formalistic" variant of the Gödel completeness theorem

Tags: logic, reference-request, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I think, the following variant of the Gödel completeness theorem must be true, but I can't find the necessary references. I would be grateful if specialists in logic could give me them (or enlighten me in case that something must be corrected).

**A question.** Joseph Shoenfield in his ["Mathematical logic"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568811357) (section 4.7) gives a definition of an *interpretation of a theory in another theory*. This notion *allows to define a model of a first order theory $T$ as its interpretation in some variant of an axiomatic set theory*, say, in MK (or in ZFC, I don't think that this choice is important.). (I understand that this is not the custom in mathematical logic, but I invite readers to look at this way, I will explain my motives later.)

Suppose now that we have a first order theory $T$. We define its model in MK in the way I described above, and consider the *class ${\mathcal M}_T$ of all models of $T$ in MK*. Each model $M\in {\mathcal M}_T$ can be considered as another first order theory, an extension by definitions of the theory MK  in the sense of [Kenneth Kunen's "Foundations of mathematics"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1904987141) (section II.15).

Moreover, we can add the symbol ${\mathcal M}_T$ into the signature of MK and the definition of ${\mathcal M}_T$ into the list of axioms of MK, and we'll get another first order theory, an extension by definition of MK. Let us denote this new first order theory by MK+${\mathcal M}_T$.

Now let us take a formula $\varphi$ in $T$. It has an analog $\varphi_M$ in each model $M\in {\mathcal M}_T$, and we can consider a formula $\varphi^*$ in MK+${\mathcal M}_T$ which states that

> $\forall M\quad M\in {\mathcal M}_T\Rightarrow \varphi_M$

My question is if the following proposition is true (up to some possible specifications):

> **Theorem**. *A formula $\varphi$ is deducible in $T$ if and only if the corresponding formula $\varphi^*$ is deducible in MK+${\mathcal M}_T$.*

As far as I understand, this can be considered as a "weakened analog" of the Gödel completeness theorem, and the stronger one must state the same about all the formulas $\varphi$ simultaneously.

**About my motives.** This comes from [one of my questions at MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/251099/are-there-textbooks-on-logic-where-the-references-to-set-theory-appear-only-afte). I believe, there must be a way to explain mathematical logic such that the references to sets and functions appear after the axiomatic construction of the set theory (and not before, as it is now). I am not a specialist in Logic (my field is Analysis), but I am interested in this because (I teach logic sometimes, and) I am writing a [textbook on university mathematics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.0824) where I am planning to add a chapter about Set theory and mathematical logic. From the discussion at MathOverflow I got an impression that the idea to simplify the exposition is not hopeless, it is possible to explain everything inside the standard principle that

> a mathematician can't use a term before giving its accurate definition.

That is why in my text (I wrote already a draft of this chapter) Set theory preceeds mathematical logic, so that I can use the notions of set and function after their formal definition. But my problem is a lack of references. I would appreciate very much if somebody could help me with this.

I asked this at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282975/a-formalistic-variant-of-the-g%C3%B6del-completeness-theorem) as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "the class ${\mathcal M}_T$ itself can be considered as a first order theory"?

Comment: Actually, mathematical logic should **precede and follow** set theory. This is because the term “mathematical logic” has 2 meanings: a language such that mathematical reasoning can be expressed in it (practical logic); study of logical notions as mathematical objects (theoretical logic). We need practical logic to reason about the axioms of set theory because they, well, contain logical constructs like quantifiers and connectives.

Comment: @EricWofsey I made some corrections in the text to clarify this.

Comment: @beroal I don't understand your point. Do you mean that it's impossible to rearrange the exposition of Mathematical logic in the way I am talking about?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this is what you want. Using any sufficiently powerful set theory (say, $\mathsf{ZFC}$), given any theory $T$, we can directly code the vocabulary of $T$ using gödel sets and have a set represent $T$ (namely the set which contains all and only the codes of the axioms of $T$). Moreover, we can directly define in the theory *both* the notion of following from a set of formulas *and* what is for a set to be a model of a theory, and then state the completeness theorem *inside* the set theory in question. So why this detour via interpretations?

Comment: @Nagase: there is a tradition in mathematical logic to understand sets and functions not as objects of an axiomatic set theory but as "platonic ideas". And all their books are writen in this style. The interpretations in the sense of Shoenfield are needed for translating this "platonic exposition" into a formal language. Look here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/251099/are-there-textbooks-on-logic-where-the-references-to-set-theory-appear-only-afte

Comment: I understand your concern to avoid platonism, but I don't see why interpretations are needed. Maybe a better way would be to develop, say, primitive recursive artihmetic, show how it captures a provability predicate through arithmetization, and then develop your preferred set theory inside the arithmetic. Why isn't this a viable option?

Comment: Set theory inside the arithmetic? I don't inderstand this (and I can't imagine how this is possible). I would think, the direct way is what I am tellng about: to translate everything into the language of Morse-Kelly theory, and the problem will disappear.

Comment: Actually, this is completely standard (if our theory is recursively axiomatized, which it should be, anyway); cf. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248965/do-set-theorists-use-informal-set-theory-as-their-meta-theory-when-talking-about/248983#248983 for an example. The idea is that we use arithmetization to develop enough *syntax* to be able to express formulas from our preferred set theory as Gödel numbers and to capture the provability predicate. Since the set theory will be a syntactic object, we can then just drop the meta-theory out of the picture and speak directly of the theory.